# Can ping any hosts but localhost. What's wrong?

Tags: networking, rhel

I got a freshly installed red hat box on a server.

I can ping another machine on the network usnig both ip and server name but I can't ping localhost or 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.4.42 (local ip)

```
[root@comp2 ~]# ping comp1
PING vcas1 (192.168.4.41) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vcas1 (192.168.4.41): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
64 bytes from vcas1 (192.168.4.41): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms

--- comp1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.100/0.102/0.104/0.002 ms
[root@comp2 ~]# 

[root@comp2 ~]# ping 192.168.4.41
PING 192.168.4.41 (192.168.4.41) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.4.41: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.4.41: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms

--- 192.168.4.41 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.105/0.112/0.119/0.007 ms
```

But I can't ping localhost or local ip address.

```
[root@comp2 ~]# ping 192.168.4.42
PING 192.168.4.42 (192.168.4.42) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.4.42 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
PING comp2 (192.168.4.42) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- comp2 ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 15999ms

[root@comp2 ~]# ping 192.168.4.42
PING 192.168.4.42 (192.168.4.42) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.4.42 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms

[root@comp2 ~]# ping localhost
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- localhost.localdomain ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

This is my /etc/hosts

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
192.168.4.41    comp1
192.168.4.42    comp2
```

and finally this is my ifconfig:

```
[root@comp2 ~]# /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:55:D4:4E:81  
          inet addr:10.0.0.14  Bcast:10.127.255.255  Mask:255.128.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:271591 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3079 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16571921 (15.8 MiB)  TX bytes:228424 (223.0 KiB)
          Memory:fbfa0000-fbfc0000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:55:D4:4E:80  
          inet addr:192.168.4.42  Bcast:192.168.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:174349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34537 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12202232 (11.6 MiB)  TX bytes:3230241 (3.0 MiB)
          Memory:fbfe0000-fc000000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:829344 (809.9 KiB)  TX bytes:829344 (809.9 KiB)
```

What's going on?

EDIT:

```
[root@comp2 ~]# /sbin/iptables -F
[root@comp2 ~]# /etc/init.d/iptables stop
Flushing firewall rules:                                   [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter                    [  OK  ]
Unloading iptables modules:                                [  OK  ]
[root@comp2 ~]# ping localhost
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- localhost.localdomain ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4999ms
```

Still nothing.

```
[root@comp2 ~]#/sbin/ip route show
192.168.4.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.4.42 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link 
10.0.0.0/9 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.14 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 

[root@comp2 ~]# /sbin/route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.4.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        *               255.128.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
default         VideoGateway.Om 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

New:

This is something I should have done already but equally from server comp1 (192.168.4.41), I can't ping comp2(192.168.4.42)

Comment: flush and switch off iptables service.

Comment: that didn't do it ^^'

Comment: ok, what does `ip route show` or `route` or `netstat -nr` say?

Comment: route add -net 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 <interface>

Comment: I can't thank you enough for helping me Nikhil.

Comment: oh ok..you are welcome :-)

Comment: I've added the results of ip route show and route in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1953/discussion-between-nikhil-and-ndefontenay)

Comment: @ndefontenay could you please post the updated route table? because i am very curious to know what was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the route table reconfiguration that is needed. Update `GATEWAY` variable in  `/etc/sysconfig/networking-scripts/ifcfg-ethX`. Route information update in `/etc/sysconfig/networking-scripts/route-ethX` is also needed. Once the proper and correct network configuration in the files are updated, restart the `network` with `/sbin/service network restart` to get the new network configuration live on the interfaces.

Comment: Would that fix the ping issue from machine vcas1 to vcas2 (the problematic one)?

Comment: not completely but we need to add other route information as well, look at the route file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

Comment: I am available on chat, if you need to take up this further.

Comment: did you mess with netmask/broadcast addresses of the interface?

Comment: I would also recommend looking at the `route` or `ip r` commands to take a look at the current routing table status.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of following command.

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`

If it is 1 then do following.

`echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`

To store it permanently do following.

```
echo "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

If value of `icmp_echo_ignore_all` is 1 then kernel ignores ICMP ECHO requests. Some sysadmins disable the ping replies to avoid ping flood(`ping -f`).

Answer (score 1):

It seem your `lo` interface has not yet been brought up. Please try the following commands:

```
ifup lo
```

OR

```
ifup -a
```